# Get Request from happstack-lite API

Tags: happstack

How would I go about getting the Request data from the happstack-lite API?  I'm trying to get the client's IP address.  From what I can tell it's in Request::rqPeer, and I get confused trying to dive into the monadic-layers of the happstack API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `askRq` in any [ServerMonad](http://www.happstack.com/docs/happstack-server-7.0.2/doc/html/happstack-server/Happstack-Server-Monads.html#t%3aServerMonad) to get at the Request, which you could pattern match on with record syntax to get the client hostname:

```
do Request {rqPeer = (host,_)} <- askRq
   ok $ "Your IP: " ++ host
```

Comment: And it looks like ServerPartT m meets the requirements for a ServerMonad.  Great, thanks.